# Fazer uma busca em um input e mostrar resultado no outro

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql

entrei no ramo de programação faz uns 6 meses, então ainda sou bemmm iniciante, inclusive, sou menor aprendiz. Estou fazendo um projeto avaliativo, pra entregar na semana que vem, gostaria de ajuda numa questão no meu código que não sei como fazer.

Por exemplo, quero colocar um CPF num input, e no outro aparecer o nome referente a pessoa daquele CPF. Tenho uma tabela no banco de dados chamada clientes, meu projeto é de um estacionamento.
Tenho um código praticamente igual a esse que funciona, mas esse apenas não funciona e não retorna erro algum.

MEU PHP:

```
<?php
$cpf_cliente = $_POST['cpf_cliente'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE cpf_cliente = '$cpf_cliente'";

$pgsql_connection = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=avanteparkdb user=postgres password=1234") or die("Sem conexão com o servidor");
$resultado = pg_fetch_all(pg_query($pgsql_connection, $query));

foreach ($resultado as $linha) {
    $resposta[] = [
        'id_cliente' => $linha['id_cliente'],
        'cpf_cliente' => $linha['cpf_cliente'],
        'nome_cliente' => $linha['nome_cliente']
    ];
}
echo json_encode($resposta);
```

MEU AJAX:

```
 $("#cpf").on("change", function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'../ajax/buscar_clientes.php',
            data: { cpf_cliente: $("#cpf").val() },
            success: function(resposta){
                var json = JSON.parse(resposta);
                $("#nome_cliente").html('');
                json.map(function(item){
                    $("#nome_cliente").append("<option value="+item.id_cliente+">"+item.cpf_cliente+item.nome_cliente+"</option>");
                })
            }
        })
        })
```

MEU HTML:

```
 <div class="label">CPF do Cliente:</div>
     <select id="cpf" name ="tamanho" class="form-control">
     <option value=""></option>

                            <?php

  $pgsql_connection = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=avanteparkdb user=postgres 
  password=1234") or die("Sem conexão com o servidor");

        $query = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
        $resultado = pg_query($pgsql_connection, $query);

        $lista = pg_fetch_all($resultado);
         pg_close($pgsql_connection);

      foreach($lista as $linha){
      ?>
      <option value="<?=$linha['id_cliente']?>"><?php echo $linha['cpf_cliente']?></option> 

      <?php
      }
      ?>

      </select>
```

INPUT NOME

```
     <label for="nome_cliente"><div class="label">Nome:</div>
     <select type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_cliente" name="nome_cliente" value=""> 
     </label>

     <option value = "" ></option>

     </select>
```

Comment: As options do seu select de id cpf, possuem como valor o id do cliente e não o cpf.

Answer (score -3):

```
<option value="<?=$linha['id_cliente']?>"><?php echo $linha['cpf_cliente']?></option>
```

No option você está passando somente o cpf do cliente. Caso você precise passar o nome junto com o cpf em input direfentes,  você terá que usar fazer assim:

```
<input type="text" name="nome_cliente" id="nome_cliente"><?php echo $linha['nome_cliente']; ?></option>

<input type="text" name="cpf_cliente" id="cpf_cliente"><?php echo $linha['cpf_cliente']; ?></option>
```

Caso não seja isso, recomendo reformular a pergunta.

obs:seu código está muito sujo. não entendi o motivo do forech pra criar um array com o resultado da query e depois usar outro forech pra mostrar os dados sendo que você poderia está usando apenas um forech pra fazer todo o processo.

Comment: bom, já entreguei esse projeto. meu código não está sujo, existem coisas que estão ali por outros motivos os quais vc desconhece.

Comment: Se você acha que receber um array, desmontar esse array pra montar outro array igual ao array original não é sujar o código, então está perfeito. Só demonstra que não tem o mínimo da base e ainda se acha prepotente.

Você está no caminho certo.